# Cuando agrego tres empleado mas, me bota error el programa

Tags: c++

Ayúdeme con ese programa, lo que quiero hacer es:

1. Pongo 3 empleado.
2. Ingreso los sueldo.
3. Me sale el menú.
4. Agrego tres empleado.

Cuando agrego el segundo empleado y quiero agregar el tercer empleado ya no me muestra el menú. Por favor alguien que me ayude.

```
int main( ){
    int total_empleados;
    int resp;
    cout<<"Cuantos empleados son:"<<endl;
    cin>> total_empleados;
    empleados numeros[total_empleados];

    for(int i=0; i<total_empleados; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese el sueldo mensual"<<endl;
        cin>>numeros[i].sueldo_mensual;

        if(numeros[i].sueldo_mensual>=150){
            numeros[i].utilidades= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual *2;
            numeros[i].bono_vacacional= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual;
            numeros[i].bono_productivo= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual *0.1;

        }else{

            numeros[i].utilidades= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual *4;
            numeros[i].bono_vacacional= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual;
            numeros[i].cesta_tickets= 200;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Podriías colocar el código de lo que estás haciendo?

Comment: Hola **Monica** Sube tu código para que podamos ayudarte pronto

Comment: Quiero subir todo el codigo pero la pagina no me deja subir todos Chic@s

Comment: **Monica** como esta declarada e tu variable numeros

Comment: struct empleados{
        int sueldo_mensual;
        int utilidades;
        int bono_vacacional;
        int bono_productivo;
        int cesta_tickets;

};

int main( ){
    int total_empleados;
    int resp;
    cout<<"Cuantos empleados son:"<<endl;
    cin>> total_empleados;
        empleados numeros[total_empleados];
Mira Nando numero esta en una estructura

Comment: Aqui esta el menu

Comment: do{
        cout<<"\n\n Bienvenido al Menu"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Agregar empleado."<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Salir."<<endl;
        cout<<"Elija una opcion:"<<endl;
        cin>>resp;
        fflush(stdin);

            switch(resp){
                case 1:
                    cout<<"Elegio AGREGAR EMPLEADO"<<endl;

                        cout<<"Total de Empleado: "<<total_empleados<<endl;

Comment: for(int i=total_empleados; i<=total_empleados; i++){

                                    cout<<"I:"<<i<<endl;
                          cout<<"Ingrese el sueldo mensual"<<endl;
                cin>>numeros[i].sueldo_mensual;
                    if(numeros[i].sueldo_mensual>=150){

Comment: numeros[i].utilidades= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual *2;
                        numeros[i].bono_vacacional= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual;
                        numeros[i].bono_productivo= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual *0.1;

Comment: }else{
                        numeros[i].utilidades= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual *4;
                        numeros[i].bono_vacacional= numeros[i].sueldo_mensual;
                        numeros[i].cesta_tickets= 200;   }

            }
        
            }
                            total_empleados+=1;
                            fflush(stdin);break;

            }
        }while(resp!=2);

Comment: **Monica** esto es lo que tengo https://onlinegdb.com/ryNwd2QYH es correcto?

Comment: Nando ->             https://onlinegdb.com/ry73RpQtB

Comment: `empleados numeros[total_empleados];` no es C++ válido (pero algunos compiladores acceptan como extensión). Preferible: `std::vector<empleados> numeros(total_empleados);`

Comment: Como seria el código..

Comment: Como sugerencia, para añadir información a la pregunta busca el enlace `editar` que está justo bajo la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Dado que `total_empleados` es una variable, la declaración de `numeros`:

```
empleados numeros[total_empleados];
```

Trata de generar un VLA (**V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray). Estos elementos **no forman parte del estándar**, luego su soporte es totalmente dependiente del compilador que estés usando. Esto quiere decir que es posible que te funcione en casa pero no en clase o al revés... no es una práctica recomendable.

Lo recomendable es reemplazar estas estructuras por:

- memoria dinámica:

  ```
  empleados * numeros = new empleados[total_empleados];

  // ...

  delete[] empleados
  ```
- memoria dinámica con punteros inteligentes:

  ```
  std::unique_ptr<empleados[]> numeros(new empleados[total_empleados]);

  // ...

  // no es necesario usar delete[]
  ```
- contenedores de la STL:

  ```
  std::vector<empleados> numeros(total_empleados);

  // ...

  // no es necesario usar delete[]
  ```

Elije la opción que más te guste y evita recurrir a los VLA.

En otro orden de cosas:

- **no uses** `fflush` con `stdin`. `fflush` es una función pensada para **dispositivos de salida**, siendo indeterminado su uso en el caso de dispositivos de entrada (es decir, en unos sistemas funcionará como esperas y en otros no).
- **no mezcles** entrada/salida propia de C y de C++. `cin` y `cout` son propios de C++, mientras que `stdin` viene heredado de C. Mezclar estos dos sistemas puede ser contraproducente ya que ambos sistemas no tiene por qué estar necesariamente sincronizados.
- Tabula correctamente el código: Mejorarás su legibilidad y te será más sencillo localizar errores en el código.

Comment: La verdad es que no  voy por ahy con el delete y el New y entonces el codigo como seria sin el New y Delete mas facil para entender por favor para c++!!. Saludo!!

Comment: @Monica si no lo entiendes es simple y llanamente porque estás aprendiendo, no porque te haya puesto código complicado. Si no quieres usar `new` y `delete` puedes declarra un array lo suficientemente grande y usar solo las posiciones que te interesan. Por ejemplo, `empleados numeros[50]` te servirá siempre que no se ingresen más de 50 registros.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos ya me salio solo tenia que poner empleados numeros[1000]. saludo!!